# Compute OpenGL matrices from optical flow

Tags: opengl, augmented-reality, opticalflow

I'm trying to implement a marker-less augmented reality application - the famous glasses virtual try-on. I use optical flow (pyramidal Lucas-Kanade) to track the user's face - this works good enough. Intially, the user is asked to place his face against a face placeholder displayed on screen. If a face & eyes are detected in that target region, I use cvGoodFeaturesToTrack to get the initial points & start tracking. This is where I'm stuck. I don't really understand  how to use the optical flow results to transform the OpenGL scene. Also, how should I set up the initial perspective so that my virtual glasses are placed exactly on the user's face (assuming that he is standing straight towards the camera, to match the placeholder)?
  I use Qt & an QGLWidget. The openCV image is displayed as a texture in OpenGL, using orthogonal projection. I don't calibrate the camera. What I found as reference is http://www.morethantechnical.com/2010/11/10/20-lines-ar-in-opencv-wcode/. It's basically almost exactly what I need, but I didn't managed to make it work for me (just a black screen if I don't use orthogonal projection / solvePnP throws exception, etc). There are a couple of differences from my approach, like the fact that the texture is not displayed using orthogonal projection & they have the the data for the camera calibration.
 Basically, I would like to know the basic idea of translating optical flow data to OpenGL transformations, what is the best way to go ?

Comment: There are many questions here, and in this form it's hard to answer reasonably. You should break this up into smaller chunks. If you did, you'd probably find many resources for at least OpenGL debugging. Unfortunately, the fact that it's very hard to figure out what's wrong is rather common.

Comment: Thanks for the remarks. I've edited my question. What I need help with it's just using the optical flow results to get rotation/translation matrices & the scale factor. The rest is just an explanation of what I'm trying to do.